# WCF Routing for tcp endpoints hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a sitiuation where i have to route multiple services to a single service in for a WCF app hosted in IIS.

I know i could do that using RouteTable and turning on aspnetcompatibility for http based endpoints, but is there a way to do this using tcp based endpoints ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with WCF Routing that was introduced in 4.0. For more information, see the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517421.aspx

Richard Seroter has written a good post on IIS hosting of the RoutingService here: http://seroter.wordpress.com/2009/12/16/hosting-the-wcf-4-0-routing-service-in-iis-7/ and here: http://seroter.wordpress.com/2010/03/09/simpler-way-of-hosting-the-wcf-4-0-routing-service-in-iis7/

--larsw